# chrome not loading one website

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I've been trying to connect to a single website (usepanda.com) all day in Chrome.

I've tried connecting with two entirely different internet connections. I've checked with the websites that see if the site is down for everyone or just me (I got mixed results--some said just me others said everyone).

All other websites load up properly; usepanda.com will load with different browsers. Chrome on my phone will load the webpage.

I did try a clean cache and hard reload on the page, but it just sat there loading for ages. In the developer console, it does show the html and css, but the page just reads "This webpage is unavailable". Under details, it says ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED.

I do have the panda extension on Chrome, and the content doesn't load there either--all I see is the nav bar.

I'm more curious now than anything. Any help is appreciated.
Christy

Answer (score 0):

At this very moment the site does seem to have some problems.
However, use www.usepanda.com, instead of the non-www version.